# Postman Monitor fails Error: Aborted the run because it appears to have hung

Tags: postman, postman-native-app

I am trying to set up two postman monitors to run daily at 2 and 3 AM the first one runs correctly except when the api takes longer than expected and runs for longer than 5 minutes the second runs 1 out of 3 times on average. Both collection run perfectly on their own.

Error Message:
Error: The run appears to have hung. Retrying...
Error: Aborted the run because it appears to have hung.
Steps To Reproduce

Set Postman monitor to run daily at 2 and 3 AM Collections take less than 5 minutes each.
Screenshots or Videos [Error messages IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD7qE.png)

- Operating System: Windows 10
- Platform Type: Native App
- Postman Version:  v8.12.0-canary210820-1135

Answer (score 0):

Found the Answer after talking to the Postman team. So the Error seems to be that the server hangs up apter a 5 minute time limit but doesn't notify you of the event error just the end result.